# How can I structure a .find() function that takes an array of values and returns an Object of key : values

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I would like to know if there is a better way to retrieve multiple key value pairs in an array of objects from MongoDB.

My goal is to create a function that receives an array of values that I want to search for (i.e. an `_id`) and return an Object of key value pairs where the key is the original search term.

The data could be structured as seen below:

```
'users': [
        {
          _id: '123',
          displayName: 'John Doe',
          timezone: 'America/New_York',
        },
        {
          _id: '456',
          displayName: 'Jane Doe',
          timezone: 'America/New_York',
        },
        {
          _id: '789',
          displayName: 'Ken Watanabe',
          timezone: 'America/New_York',
        }
       ]
```

The input could look like this: `['123','789']`

And the preferred output would look like this:

```
{
  '123':{
          _id: '123',
          displayName: 'John Doe',
          timezone: 'America/New_York',
        },
  '789':{
          _id: '789',
          displayName: 'Ken Watanabe',
          timezone: 'America/New_York',
        }
}
```

The data that matches the search parameters returns and the value type of that was searched for is the new corresponding key.

So far, I am using the following:

```
let data = await  db.collection(collection).find( { _id : { $in : _ids }  }).toArray();
```

However, this only stores the data in an array of Objects:

```
       [
        {
          _id: '123',
          displayName: 'John Doe',
          timezone: 'America/New_York',
        },
        {
          _id: '789',
          displayName: 'Ken Watanabe',
          timezone: 'America/New_York',
        }
       ]
```

This can be parsed using Object.entries(), but perhaps there is a better way to retrieve the data.

Edit. Marcus has already provided an excellent answer below in case you are looking to solve this problem server side. Be sure to check it out.

To clarify, I am looking for a solution that retrieves the desired output from the database without needing to modify the data after arrival.

Sergio has suggested `.agregate()` which I will look into now. If I find a solution before someone else, I will be sure to update with an answer.

Comment: You probably could achieve this in the database using `aggregate`, but I'd simply transform the array in the app (like shown in Marcus' answer, for example)

Comment: Sergio, could you please tell me why you'd transform the array as in Marcus' answer rather than in the DB call?

Comment: For simplicity. It's a very simple query and a very straightforward transformation. The equivalent `aggregate()` call will be more expensive, cognitively. IMHO, naturally.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
const result = {};
users.map((item) =>result[item._id] = item)
```

Comment: Markus, your answer works very well. Thank you.

However it isn't quite what I am looking to achieve.  I am looking for a solution closer to what Sergio suggested, to achieve this in the database. 

I will mark this as the correct answer if this is the better way to do it.

Comment: No worries, best of luck to you! I mustve misread the question my apologies. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce()` to iterate through and the `spread {...}` syntax to accumulate the new array of objects

```
let users = data.users.reduce((b, a) => 
   (search.includes(a._id) ? // if our user id is a match
   { ...b, ...{[a._id]: a}} : b) // return the current object with the new user object added in
   , {})
```

```js
let data = {
  users: [{ _id: '123',displayName: 'John Doe',timezone: 'America/New_York'},
    {_id: '456',displayName: 'Jane Doe',timezone: 'America/New_York'},
    {_id: '789',displayName: 'Ken Watanabe',timezone: 'America/New_York'}]}
let search = ['123', '789'];
let users = data.users.reduce((b, a) => 
   (search.includes(a._id) ? 
   { ...b, ...{[a._id]: a}} : b)
   , {})

console.log(users)
```